# How to add new theme name to grunt CLI command to run grunt tool in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta, parent-child-theme, grunt

When we clone new theme from existing parent theme in Magento 2. How we can execute `less:newThemName` command using grunt CLI ?

As well as how `grunt watch` will look any changes into newly created theme ?

I have created new theme `app\design\frontend\Vendor\luma2`

My theme.xml is

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Luma 2</title> <!-- your theme's name -->
    <parent>Magento/luma</parent> <!-- the parent theme, in case your theme inherits from an existing theme -->
    <media>
        <preview_image>media/preview.png</preview_image> <!-- the path to your theme's preview image -->
    </media>
</theme>
```

Comment: Have you installed grunt ?

Comment: Yes, I have installed grunt. As I mentioned Grunt is working fine. Issue is mentioned in question.

Answer (score 5):

Goto \dev\tools\grunt\configs, Open themes.js and add the part as 
shown in the image.

[image]

Now Open less.js
 and add the part shown in the image
[image]

Now you can run grunt less:luma2 task, and it will generate the pub static files for the theme

Comment: Hi Taral, Should we need to add it manually every time for new theme creation of Magento 2?

Comment: Yes, when ever you add new theme, you will need to add its details to the to files mentioned above.

Comment: Is there another option to add it to grunt? (include .js files via XML config?) i see that whole grunt folder by default is in .gitignore

Comment: how can do these things with clis instead of edit less.js and thems.js