# Grunt configuration Magento 2

Tags: magento2, less, grunt

Using the php bin/magento and deploying static content does work without throwing errors.  This means that it's just having a problem getting Grunt going.

```
Processed Area: frontend, Locale: en_US, Theme: Vendor/broadway, File type: less.
-> css/styles-m.less
>> [Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException]                                               
>>   The "/Users/my_username/Sites/sample/dir/dth.dev/" file doesn't exist or not a file
```

I have read this post [How to add new theme name to grunt CLI command to run grunt tool in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86164/how-to-add-new-theme-name-to-grunt-cli-command-to-run-grunt-tool-in-magento-2/86228#86228) and have a further question.  What does a typical Gruntfile.js look like so that I can configure Grunt properly?

I am also referring to the dev docs http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html#grunt_prereq.  In my `/dev/tools/grunt/configs` I have already added my theme there.

```
broadway: {
    area: 'frontend',
    name: 'Vendor/broadway',
    locale: 'en_US',
    files: [
        'css/styles-m',
        'css/styles-1'
    ],
    dsl: 'less'
},
```

now this path `/Users/my_username/Sites/sample/dir/dth.dev/` is actually where my root Magento is installed.  So it just isn't linking up properly somehow.

`grunt exec:broadway`
is the command I ran.

> Currently I am inheriting from Luma, but I can also inherit from Blank if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
'css/styles-1'
```

this line should not be the number one (1) it should be a lower case L 'l'

```
'css/styles-l'
```

Also, I did not type this out.  I did copy and paste, but I can't remember from which guide.

Comment: turns out I was missing a comma ','

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [Compile LESS with Grunt](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html).