# How to add new theme name to grunt CLI command to run grunt tool in Magento 2 with CLI commands instead of editing less.js and themes.js file?

Tags: magento2, theme, less, grunt

I read  [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86164/how-to-add-new-theme-name-to-grunt-cli-command-to-run-grunt-tool-in-magento-2) , But I wanna add new theme name to grunt CLI command with some CLI commands not editing a less.js and thmemes.js  manually.Is there any solution for this 
something Like (magento2 add-new-them-to-grunt --theme-name-- --theme-files--)